# Change class of variable

Tags: matlab

There are some symbolic variables in my program and some of them have float values, can I change the class of my variable to simple variable cause lots of functions have problem with symbolic parameters, such as "sind" and etc.

you could see my variables have float value but they are symbolic

[image]

Comment: There's no code here, which makes us sad. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: What is a simple variable?

Comment: my means from simple variable is the variable with class of double or etc

Comment: I do hope that screenshot is not your definition of "code", because all I see is you calling some variables. Besides, codes belongs in the question as code formatting, not as a screenshot. All those things you show are symbols btb ( `3/5` would be resolved as `0.6` in a float).

Comment: Those don't look like floats to me, they look like fractions...

Comment: they are in a big program and I wanna use them in another program but they are symbolic and it made some problem for using them directly.

Comment: Did you try googling for this: first result is this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `double`, `char`, `single`, `logical`, `uint8`, `int8`, etc. to coerce your variable (including symbolic variables) to a given class.

```
% Convert to double precision
x_double = double(x);

% Convert to single precision
x_single = single(x);
```